# custom aggregate outside of jqxgrid

Tags: aggregation, jqwidget

i got TypeError: e is null
    ...numberInput.attr("disabled",true)}else{n.host.removeClass(c.toThemeProperty("jqx...
when i try to get aggregate value from jqwidget grid.pls tell me what is the mistake i had,i suspect this `$("#tblInvoices").jqxGrid('getcolumnaggregateddata', 'gainPrice', ['min', 'max']);`

```
var source ={   
datatype: "json",
url: url,
data: {invoice_id: $("#id").val()},
datafields: [
            { name: 'roundNo' },
            { name: 'engineNo'},
            { name: 'chasiNo'},
            { name: 'model_id'},
            { name: 'gainPrice'},
            { name: 'selingPrice'},
            { name: 'remark'}
            ],


               addrow: function (rowid, rowdata, position, commit) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send insert command
                    var id=$("#id").val();
                    var data = "insert=true&invoice_id="+id+"&"+ $.param(rowdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: url,
                        data: data,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // insert command is executed.
                            commit(true);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            commit(false);
                        }
                    });
                },//end  add row

                 deleterow: function (rowid, commit) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send delete command
                    var data = "delete=true&" + $.param({ roundNo: rowid });
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: url,
                        cache: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // delete command is executed.
                            commit(true);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            commit(false);
                        }
                    });
                },
                updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) {
                    // synchronize with the server - send update command
                     var id=$("#id").val();
                    var data = "update=true&invoice_id="+id+"&"+ $.param(rowdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: url,
                        cache: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            // update command is executed.
                            commit(true);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            commit(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
};
 var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
//..............................................................

$( "#tblInvoices").jqxGrid({
theme: 'darkblue',
source: dataAdapter,
columnsresize: true,
showaggregates: true,
showstatusbar: true,
statusbarheight: 50,
selectionmode: 'singlecell',
editable: true,
columns: [
            { datafield: 'roundNo', text: 'R/N', type: 'text',  width: 60 },
            { datafield: 'engineNo', text: 'Engine No', type: 'text',  width: 100 },
            { datafield: 'chasiNo', text: 'Chasi No', type: 'text',  width: 100 },
            { datafield: 'model_id', text: 'Model No',  type: 'text',  width: 100 },
            { datafield: 'gainPrice', text: 'Gain Price', cellsformat: 'n2',  width: 60 ,aggregates: ['min', 'max']},
            { datafield: 'selingPrice', text: 'Seling Price', type: 'text',  width: 60,aggregates: [{ 'Total':
                          function (aggregatedValue, currentValue) {
                              if (currentValue) {
                                  return aggregatedValue + 1;

                              }
                              return aggregatedValue;
                          }
                      }] },
            { datafield: 'remark', text: 'Remark', type: 'text',  width: 120 }
            ]
});
//end grid loadi..
 var ta = $("#tblInvoices").jqxGrid('getcolumnaggregateddata', 'gainPrice', ['min', 'max']);
   alert(ta.min);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you invoke getcolumnaggregateddata while the Grid is not yet loaded and rendered. Call that within the Grid's ready callback or inside its bindingcomplete event handler and you'll get better results.